# Javascript - Google IMA SDK covers skip button

Tags: javascript, vast, google-ima

I'm using Google IMA SDK for VAST integration on my website but I've encountered a serious problem.

Sometimes loaded video ads have skip button and in most cases this button is clickable, but sometimes the button is behind a transparent layer that prevents clicks.
If I give it `visibility: hidden` or remove it by hand the skip button works properly, but there is no way to check if the button is currently blocked.

In the image below I marked the layer that blocks the skip button.

Do you know how to fix it?

[image: Image showing transparent layer over video]